# cross compile gdisk for arm

Tags: android, arm, cross-compiling

My build machine is 
`android@builduntu-VM:~/gdisk-0.8.10$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid`

I am trying to compile for armeabi-v7a (Android) and so i have downloaded the arm-linux-androideabi tool chain located at /usr/arm...

`android@builduntu-VM:~/gdisk-0.8.10$ cd /usr
android@builduntu-VM:/usr$ ls
arm-linux-androideabi  arm-linux-gnueabi  arm-linux-gnueabihf  bin  games  include  lib  lib32  libx32  local  sbin  share  src  x86_64-linux-gnu`

My makefile looks like this

`CC=gcc`

`CXX=g++`

`CFLAGS+=-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

`#CXXFLAGS+=-Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D USE_UTF16`

`CXXFLAGS+=-Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

`LDFLAGS+=`

`LIB_NAMES=crc32 support guid gptpart mbrpart basicmbr mbr gpt bsd parttypes attributes diskio diskio-unix`

`MBR_LIBS=support diskio diskio-unix basicmbr mbrpart`

`LIB_OBJS=$(LIB_NAMES:=.o)`

`MBR_LIB_OBJS=$(MBR_LIBS:=.o)`

`LIB_HEADERS=$(LIB_NAMES:=.h)`

`DEPEND= makedepend $(CXXFLAGS)`

I used export to set my CC variable

```
`android@builduntu-VM:/usr/arm-linux-androideabi/bin$ export CC="/usr/arm-linux-androideabi/"`
```

`android@builduntu-VM:/usr/arm-linux-androideabi/bin$ echo $CC`

`/usr/arm-linux-androideabi/`

When I run make and check the file the file is compiled for the wrong architecture.  What am I doing wrong?

```
`android@builduntu-VM:~/gdisk-0.8.10$ file gdisk`
```

`gdisk: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=3d45ba9c70e1f17380da4669047ef67ace3a083a, not stripped`